# Is there a way to use Google scripts to change Gmail snooze labeling?

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, gmail

With the new Gmail, when threads are snoozed, they reappear with the "Snoozed X Days Ago" annotation.  Additionally, they are then sorted based on unsnooze date (i.e., when they are moved into the inbox) and not on the date of the last received message in the thread as they are normally.  I can't find anything in the Google Apps Script reference which would indicate it is possible to change these thread attributes.

My goal is to be able to sort the messages based on the last received date as they are otherwise sorted.  There must be another attribute somewhere related to snooze by which they are sorted and removing that attribute or setting it to the same date as the last received would then sort the threads by that date.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear where or how you plan to use any code you are writing, or if you're looking for UI options, etc

Comment: Ideally, I would use a trigger to run a script (say at 1AM) to remove the snooze tags and restore the original sorting date (whatever fields those might be) so the emails in the inbox would be sorted as if they had never been snoozed.  On a related note, these are thread related and not message related tags as when conversation mode is turned off, the messages are sorted correctly regardless of snooze.

Comment: To me it still sounds like you're trying to change the server-side sort, when your web client will sort the messages anyway. You can't use Apps Script to configure your local client - Apps Script runs on Google's servers.

Comment: I get the Apps Script runs on Google's servers.  I use scripts quite a bit to manage my Google tasks and emails.  I use Google web interface to access my email, not a local client, so it is Google's server sorting the emails, not my client.  All I'm looking for is to find out if anyone knows the names of the fields which Google uses to identify Snooze times and dates.  Thanks!